# Mongoid queries are fast but converting to results takes time

Tags: ruby, mongoid

Mongoid queries are fast. For example if it a query which returns 300 documents takes about 10 miliseconds but if I do

to_a or entries to get the results takes time.

Is there any other way to reduce the time lag.

Comment: You can use `each` instead of `to_a` as that will use the underlying mogodb cursor and assign one object at a time, which would roughly evaluate to using lesser memory footprint. Although am not sure if it will speed things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't look at the source code yet, but Mongoid queries are [lazily evaluated](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying.html).

Which means, your first call to the criteria does not touch the database, and Mongoid  actually really fetch the data when you do 'to_a' or 'entries' hence the time lag.